# Pandas - Subtract two columns in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe (df['time']) by subtracting  two datetime64 columns, using a groupby.

```
df_oswp['time'] = df_oswp.groupby('TDateID').transform(lambda x: x['EventTimestamp'] -x['EventTimestamp'])
```

As its written now, I'd excpect df_oswp['time'] to be 0 for all values.

This gives me a "KeyError" of 'EventTimestamp' though.

I have also tried:

```
df_oswp['time'] = df_oswp.groupby('TDateID').apply(lambda x: x['EventTimestamp'] -x['EventTimestamp'].
```

That gives the error:

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

 <...>
    df_oswp['time'] = df_oswp.groupby('TDateID').apply(lambda x: x['EventTimestamp'] -x['EventTimestamp'])

<...>
raise TypeError(

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Comment: Could you show `df` for demo?

Comment: Why would you subtract a column from itself? If you want 0, why not just write 0?

Comment: please provide the model dataframe